# How to insert 128 bit integers into Oracle using OCI?

Tags: c, oracle, oracle-call-interface

Currently using the OCIBindByPos, C Applications can bind 32bit and 64bit  integers into Oracle cursor.

Please advice how we can bind 64bit integers into OCI.

Oracle anyway support to the 64bit large numbers in NUMBER(38) columns.

Comment: You should maybe first decide what you are asking: 64 or 128 bits (text and heading disagree)?

Comment: what about OCINumberFromText ? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28395/oci19map003.htm#i460199 .